# Arduino 16x2 LCD not displaying in tinkercad circuit (Arduino Uno board)

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to print text on a 16x2 lcd display with use of the Liquid Crystal library, but the lcd doesn't give a response whatsoever. The code is simple but it is not working in my case:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Servo.h> 

//Digital pins
const int d_pin_lcd_D7 = 2, d_pin_lcd_D6 = 3, d_pin_lcd_D5 = 4,
d_pin_lcd_D4 = 5, d_pin_switch = 6, d_pin_button = 7, d_pin_led_green = 8, 
d_pin_led_yellow = 9, d_pin_led_red = 10, 
d_pin_lcd_EN = 11, d_pin_lcd_RS= 12, d_pin_servo = 13;

// Analog pins
const int a_pin_a = 0;

LiquidCrystal lcd(d_pin_lcd_RS, d_pin_lcd_EN, d_pin_lcd_D4, d_pin_lcd_D5, d_pin_lcd_D6, d_pin_lcd_D7);

void setup()
{
  //LCD setup
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("Hello world!"); 
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Keep in mind I am still a complete beginner in Arduino so the more info I can get the better! There might be something wrong with the board setup, but I pretty much replicated the Arduino example of a 16x2 lcd display setup, including the 10 kOhm potentiometer. Thanks in advance!

[image: A picture of the board in Tinkercad circuits]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this capability of Tinkercad, but if it's accurately simulating a typical solderless breadboard, then the two components at the right end (servo, temperature sensor?) are plugged into a vertical row of holes, and are therefore shorted together.  Since each one is connected to both sides of the power supply, you're shorting out the power supply.

Comment: Hahaha that's it! Thanks alot sir.